# Password is not working in ubuntu after turning on my computer

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, password-recovery

I have a user in my **ubuntu 20.04**. When I turn on my computer, *it requires password. I write my password , it works*. So far So good.

Problem is when I write **sudo or anything that require**s  password my password does not work. I have **resetted my root password** from *Recovery Mod*, but again it does not work. I don't know what to do. I have spent 2-3 days to figure it out, no success still.

Comment: Did you set a BIOS password which you need to enter to start the computer? What do you mean with `root password`, password for the user root or password for the normal user?

Comment: What I mean  by root password is  what it requires when I write sudo.

Comment: Then we'd need a detailed explanation how you resetted your "root password".

Comment: For sudo you need to use your own password, the one you use for login.

Comment: @SorenA  I write it does not work

Comment: @mook765 I tried method 1 here .https://www.maketecheasier.com/reset-root-password-linux/

Comment: maybe on login page you have different locale set than wen you type password for `sudo` ?

Comment: No, I make password visible and see it . They are identical. @pLumo

Comment: Sounds that you set the password for the root user, not for your normal user. The guide you linked describes both. So which command did you use, `passwd root` or `passwd username`?

Comment: I tried both @mook765